# How to display average instead of the grand total in Odoo pivot table?

Tags: xml, graph, pivot, odoo

I want to display the the column average instead of the column grand total in Odoo Pivot table.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try by using the *avg* attribute in the field

Comment: Thanks Alessandro Ruffolo.
But in pivot table there is no any attribute like avg.

Answer (score 0):

You can specifiy the group operator on the field level
example

```
allocation_percentage = fields.Float(
    string='Allocation (%)',
    group_operator='avg',
    readonly=True,
    default=0
)
```